# Laravel 5.2 Ajax "Internal Server Error"

Tags: ajax, laravel, server, internal

I can do what I want! I tried all the 1000 hints I found, but nothing worked.
I always get "Internal Server Error".
That what I want is to call the MyController@myurl

My 1000th question why I got "Internal Server Error" is:

routes.php:

```
Route::post( '/myurl', [
        'uses' => 'MyController@myurl',
        'as'   => 'myurl',
    ] );
```

my.blade.php:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script>var url = "{{ URL::to('/myurl') }}";</script>

<script>
$( document ).ready( function () {
    callmyfunc();
    function callmyfunc() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax( {
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function ( feedback ) {
                }
            } );
        }
} );
</script>
```

Comment: What's in `storage/logs/laravel.log`? A 500 error should put an entry in there.

Comment: try adding the error callback to the ajax so you can output any of the errors .error: function (xhr, opts, showError) {console.log(xhr);console.log(showError);} this might give you a better idea why, also your not sending through any data? then if possible post the error, seems it might be more than just the above code

Comment: Did you tried to access /myurl directly from browser?

Comment: Ditch the `header` and try adding the csrf to the data..wait - where's the data for the POST request?

Comment: Please see `Browser Dev tools > Network (your request) > preview (tab)` for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your hints of the log file. In the log I could see the reason for that was the class DB was not known, because of not using "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB".

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with an empty POST request exactly?

Comment: I just want to call the method myurl(). It works now. But if I want the Javascript function callmyfunc() to be called by  setInterval() every minute, so the function is called exactly 1 time. How can I refresh the token?

Comment: You might want to use GET instead. POST is for posting for form variables, queries, etc. Tokens' refresh on page load (I believe)

Comment: Thank you all! Now I use GET. But the token seems not to be refreshed bei using ajax. How can I do that without loading the page again every minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once sent the token is no longer valid. I just wanted the page to be loaded silently by ajax every 10 seconds. So I have to regenerate a new token manually with another ajax-function before I call myfunction.

```
// routes.php
Route::get( '/myurl', [
    'uses' => 'MyController@myurl',
    'as'   => 'myurl',
] );

Route::get('/refresh_csrf', function(){
    return csrf_token();
});


<!--  blade  -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script>var url_toCall = "{{ URL::to('/myurl') }}";</script>
<script>var url_refresh = "{{ URL::to('/refresh_csrf') }}";</script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        setInterval( refreshToken, 10000  );
        setInterval( callMyFunction, 10000 );
        setInterval( refreshToken, 10000  );

        function callMyFunction() {
            $.ajaxSetup( {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $( 'meta[name="csrf-token"]' ).attr( 'content' )
                }
            } );
            $.ajax( {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url_toCall,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function ( feedback ) {
                }
            } );
        }
        function refreshToken() {
            $.ajaxSetup( {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $( 'meta[name="csrf-token"]' ).attr( 'content' )
                }
            } );
            $.ajax( {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url_refresh,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function ( feedback ) {
                    $( 'meta[name=csrf-token]' ).remove();
                    $( 'head' ).append( '<meta name="csrf-token" content="' + feedback + '">' );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
</script>
```